# inserting document of collections to another collections in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i have two different collection of documents in a mongodb database. in my **recruits** collection i have plenty of documents. and i want to add the **document** from *recruit* collections to *employee* collections
here is part of my code

```
function register(){
        $http({
            url:'/employee',
            method:'post',
            data:data // data is what i get from findById query.
        }).then(function(result){
            vm.cancel();
            vm.toast();
        },function(err){
            console.log(err);
        })
```

here data is what i get from findById  from recruits collections. now same data i want to store in employees collection.i tried so:

```
var emp = require('../models/employees.js');
 router.post('/',function(req,res){
console.log(req.body);
var register = new emp(req.body);
//console.log(register);
register.save(function(err, respond) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    } else {
        res.json(respond);
    }
})
});
```

i think its fine with the code my console shows me

```
MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error index: humanResource.employees.$_id_ dup
 key: { : ObjectId('57395146b4c73790056a3770') }
```

any one suggest me how to insert such document in another collections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You error is saying that the document you are creating has a _id which already exists in employees collection.
The problem is that you are receiving recruit data and directly passing it to the employees collection along with the _id which is passed from the recruit. You should try copying the data but excluding the _id field. Mongo will automatically generate a _id for your employees collection.
something like this,

```
var emp = require('../models/employees.js');
router.post('/',function(req,res){
      console.log(req.body);
       delete req.body._id;
      var register = new emp(req.body);
      register.save(function(err, respond) {
if (err) {
      throw err;
} else {
     res.json(respond);
}
});
```